# When mapping through an array check next item property

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm currently mapping through an array i.e.

```
contents.map((content) => {
 switch(content.type) {
   case: 1
     console.log("type is one and next type is ..");
   case: 2
     console.log("type is two")
 }
})
```

And as you can see in case 1 I need to grab type of next item. I know that this is possible using for loop with i increment, but need to do it within a map. I'm open for suggestions using libraries like lodash (wasn't able to find anything in the documentation).

Comment: Why are you constrained to the map function?

Comment: You could reverse the array before mapping, then the previous element would actually be the next element. That seems a silly idea though, extra computation when a for loop would do it

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map` calls it's callback actually with **3** parameters:

```
currentValue // current element
index // current index
array // original array
```

That means you can of course access the array via it's index within a callback routine. For instance:

```
contents.map((content, index, array) => {
    switch(content.type) {
        case 1:
            console.log("type is one and next type is: ", array[index+1] ? array[index+1].type : 'empty');
            break;
        case 2:
            console.log("type is two")
            break;
    }
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/z1sztd58/
Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Can you explain that one liner if condition checking for `array[index+1]` , I'm not really good with those.

Comment: It will just check if there is an valid element after the current. If we skip that check, the interpretator will throw an error if we are at the last element.

Comment: @jAndy accessing a not existent index of an array does not throw an error in javascript. It returns undefined.

Comment: If a `void` function is used, change `.map((content) => {...})` for `.forEach((content) => {...})`. As Ashwin Balamohan mention in his answer,  `map` must return array.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `Array.prototype.map` requires you to return the mapped value, which you aren't doing.

In a simple example:

```
const primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13];

const primesSquared = primes.map((prime) => {
  return prime * prime;
});
```

`Array.prototype.map` takes three arguments:

- element: the current array element
- index: the index of the current element within the array
- array: the entire array

You've also got a syntax error in your switch statement. Note the position of the `:` in the `case` statement in the example below.

You could accomplish what you're trying to do with something like the following:

```
const newArray = oldArray.map((elem, index, array) => {
  switch(elem.type) {
    case 1:
      return "something";
    case 2:
      return "something else";
    default:
      return "default value";
  }
});
```

Without using a switch statement, you can easily accomplish what you're trying to accomplish:

```
const newArray = oldArray.map((elem, index, array) => {
  if (index+1 < array.length && elem < array[index+1]) { //ensure you're not at the end of the array before checking your condition
    return "something";
  } else {
    return "something else"; 
  }
});
```

Refs:

- Switch statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch
- Map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map